# what are good practices / strategies for making content embeddable on external websites?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I have HTML/JavaScript content on my website that I want other websites to be able to embed.

What are some good strategies? Should I send json with a script to embed? Should I create an iframe for the widget?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Can somebody describe how it's done in general? How does one allow settings? Through rest?

Comment: As many other does : Do both js and iframe, letting the other webmaster choose the way he wants for his own site.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the intent of your content -- I've been happy with iframes in the past, but sometimes I prefer being able to load external content with ajax.  I usually try to avoid iframes because they are hard to skin.